# Uniqueness of the ODE solutions

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Say we have a **continuous** function (perhaps not everywhere differentiable) that satisfies an ODE $y^\prime(x)=h(y(x),x)$ **for almost all** $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Are the any references for that deal with basic ODE questions (existence, uniqueness) for these class of solutions? If so which ones you would recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mere *continuity* is not enough for viable theory. Indeed, the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is continuous and satisfies $y'(x)=0$ for almost all $x$. So do linear combinations of its shifts, and a countless number of other similar functions $y$. So we don't have anything like a uniqueness theorem in this  context.

The appropriate assumption on $y$ is *[absolute continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity)*. This is equivalent to $y$ being an indefinite integral of   a Lebesgue integrable function (which agrees with $y'$, of course). We can recast the problem as an integral equation 
$$y(x) = y_0+ \int_{x_0}^x h(y(t),t)\,dt $$ 
and perhaps attempt the Picard iteration.

A classical existence result for  equations with discontinuous $h$ is [Carathéodory's existence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_existence_theorem). Under additional assumption one can get  uniqueness: see the notes [On Discontinuous Differential Equations](https://www.math.psu.edu/bressan/PSPDF/discontODE00.pdf) by Bressan and Shen, where further references may be found.